# Uploading a file with ReactJS and Node

Tags: node.js, file, upload

I'm trying to use React and Node/Express to upload a file. The node portion works, as tested with Postman. However, I can't seem to get react to send the file correctly. Below is my code.

React

```
class AddDocumentModal extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        file: null
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
}
onChange(e){
    this.setState({
        file:e.target.files
    })
    console.log(this.state.file)
}

fileUpload(event){
    console.log(this.state.file)
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file',this.state.file)
    let fetchURL = this.props.baseURL + "uploadFile"
    let fetchOptions = {
        method: "post",
        body:formData
    }
    console.log(fetchOptions)
    fetch(fetchURL,fetchOptions).then(result=>{
        console.log(result)
    })
}
```

Node

```
exports.uploadFile = (req,res)=>{
console.log(req.files);
let file = req.files.file;

file.mv(`${__dirname}/public/${file.name}`, function(err) {

    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    res.json({file: `public/${file.name}`});
  });
}
```

Both req.body and req.files are an empty set. Any advice?

Comment: check if the URL used in react app matches to the server api

Comment: @beingsrv thank you for the response .the server responds with a status 500 and the console.logs work on the server side so that would not be the issue.

Comment: What is the result of fetch that you are logging